# How to get maximum 3 tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am building my own attention model in seq2seq based on TensorFlow. I was wondering how can I do something as following pseudo-code in TensorFlow:

```
att = [0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.2]# This is a tensor or a list of tensors
result = maximum3numbers(att)
```

Acceptable result could be:

```
result = [0.9,0.5,0.3]
```

or

```
result = [4,2,1]
```

Comment: Quick and Dirty: `sorted(att)[:-3]` ?

Comment: Thanks, just edit my question to avoid misunderstanding. @SuperSaiyan

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the top_k operator should do what you need:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k